# Why not support overlapped UDP in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, udp

```
{ok,Socket} = gen_udp:open(9000, [binary,{active,false}, {reuseaddr,true}]),

Pid0 = spawn_link( fun() -> loop_passive( Socket ) end ),

Pid1 = spawn_link( fun() -> loop_passive( Socket ) end ) --> error
.. (many overlapped receiving per a binded socket)
N

loop_passive(Socket) ->
   case gen_udp:recv(Socket, 0) of
     {ok, {Addr,Port,Packet}} ->
        process(Socket,Addr,Port,Packet),
        loop_passive(Socket);
     Error ->
          io:format("udp_passive error: ~p~n", [Error])
    end.
```

I'll make scalabe UDP server.
Erlang UDP mechanism was simple once at a time.
Ever, there is not another way?

Comment: Sorry, what was the question again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us look at that code where it is readable:

```
 {ok,Socket} = gen_udp:open(9000, [binary,{active,false}, {reuseaddr,true}]),
 Pid0 = spawn_link( fun() ->
           loop_passive( Socket ) end ),
 Pid1 = spawn_link( fun() ->
           loop_passive( Socket ) end ).
```

This means that `self()` opens the UDP socket, and `Pid0` and `Pid1` gets passed the resulting socket. Note that `self()` (the process running the above code) is the controlling process of the socket.

```
 loop_passive(Socket) ->
   case gen_udp:recv(Socket, 0) of
      {ok, {Addr,Port,Packet}} ->
           process(Socket,Addr,Port,Packet),
           loop_passive(Socket);
      Error -> io:format("udp_passive error: ~p~n", [Error])
   end.
```

This is just a simple loop on incoming packets. It means that `Pid0` and `Pid1` are the ones that are reading off data from the socket, whenever goes first.

The usual problems in this case are:

- The controlling process dies and thus the socket is closed